# Comment traduire/quel est l'équivalent de « healthcare safety professional » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie, santé-et-médecine

Comment traduit-on ou quel est l'équivalent de « healthcare safety professional » ? Ce peut être, par exemple, une personne en charge d'un programme de pharmacovigilance au sein d'une société. Je peux traduire mot à mot les trois mots (soins de santé/sécurité/professionnel) formant le nom composé mais je cherche une appellation en usage et étayée.

Comment: « Sécurité (souvent associé à « qualité ») des soins »  est un terme standard employé par la HAS. Rarement « soins de santé ». Il existe en France une « certification pour la qualité des soins », je ne sais pas si c'est l'équivalent exact de la *Certified Healthcare Safety Professional Certificate* mais je me contenterais bien de « soins » pour *healthcare*, le contexte faisant le reste.  Et pour rendre  en français le double complément de noms utilisé en anglais, je me tournerais vers « en charge de » expression qui rend bien le lien entre la personne et l'objet.

Comment: Ce qui mène à « (un) professionnel en charge de la sécurité des soins ». Pour garder « santé » si le contexte n'est pas clair, on peut associer le mot à professionnel : « professionnel de santé en charge de la qualité des soins ».

Comment: @None Merci, utile, pourquoi ne pas verser cette réponse dans une réponse. La certification dont vous parlez vise des établissements et non pas des professionnels. Différemment mais relié, on trouve pour « drug safety specialist » « spécialiste de l'innocuité des médicaments ». Santé Canada donne « professionnel des soins de santé » ou « professionnel de la santé » pour « health care professional », et aussi « innocuité » pour « health safety » dans différents contextes. Dans le contexte de la pharmacovigilance en entreprise, il n'y a pas de soins en soi, il s'agit de produits commercialisés.

Answer (score 1):

> « Sécurité (souvent associé à « qualité ») des soins » est un terme
> standard employé par la HAS. Rarement « soins de santé ». Il existe en
> France une « certification pour la qualité des soins », je ne sais pas
> si c'est l'équivalent exact de la *Certified Healthcare Safety
> Professional Certificate* mais je me contenterais bien de « soins »
> pour *healthcare*, le contexte faisant le reste. Et pour rendre en
> français le double complément de noms utilisé en anglais, je me
> tournerais vers « en charge de » expression qui rend bien le lien
> entre la personne et l'objet.
>
> Ce qui mène à « (un) professionnel en charge de la sécurité des soins
> ». Pour garder « santé » si le contexte n'est pas clair, on peut
> associer le mot à professionnel : « professionnel de santé en charge
> de la qualité des soins ».
>
> *None*, en commentaires ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54191/comment-traduire-quel-est-l%C3%A9quivalent-de-healthcare-safety-professional#comment115512_54191), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54191/comment-traduire-quel-est-l%C3%A9quivalent-de-healthcare-safety-professional#comment115513_54191))

Answer (score 1):

Pour un étranger au domaine, le terme d'origine est ambigu: *healthcare safety* m'évoque *a priori* la sécurité des patients ET celle des soignants.

Pour Gougueule, la 1ère expression est ~60x plus fréquente que la 2ème. En comparaison, "sécurité des actes de soin", "de soins" ou "de santé" sont rarissimes quoiqu'attestés.

Après réflexion, je perçois que j'ai inconsciemment exclu la sécurité des infrastructures ou de leur personnel non-soignant (techniciens, administratifs, ouvriers,... ), voire des visiteurs. Questionnons WP:

Pour *healthcare safety*, en.WP me renvoie à l'article *patient safety* où ne figure pas cette expression: seulement *safety in health care* (une occurrence, sans définition).

Enfin, fr.WP n'a d'article que pour "Sécurité du patient", dans lequel elle est distinguée de celle des soins:

> [le PNSP développe] la recherche sur la sécurité des soins
> et la sécurité du patient dans les essais cliniques.

Conclusion: le Web parle surtout de la sécurité du patient, une sous-catégorie de la sécurité des soins dont le lecteur est censé connaître le périmètre: toutes les parties prenantes aux soins de santé (et pas d'hygiène, cosmétiques etc).  Donc:

"Professionnel de la sécurité des soins".